# Repeating groups of arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Let's say that I want to enter info about multiple users from the command line AND that each user has multiple data associated with it.

Is it possible (syntactically permissible) to use `argparse` to parse something like `myprpgrm.py --user john --email john@doe.com --valid Y --user jane --email jane@doe.com --valid N`?

As you can see, each user should have 3 parameters associated with it - a name, an email and a valid flag.

Can `argparse` make sure that if a user parameter is seen, it must be accompanied by an email parameter and a validity parameter?

And can it give me the grouped information when I add multiple users, each with 3 parameters?

---

[Update] Could this be achieved somehow with [Argument Groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups)?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: Sorry, @GNAT, I just get so confused (and dismayed by the downvotes). I thought the decider was "if you are standing at a whiteboard, ask Programmers. If you are sitting at a keyboard ask S.O".  I am asking here if this is even possible, so thought this to be the best place to ask. If I go to S.O they will jump all over me for not posting code (of something which may not be codeable). Please advise where I should post this in the S:E hierarchy - if at all. Thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine one standing in front of whiteboard discussing concrete details of using [argparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/argparse)

Comment: Well, actually, the discussion is "how do we get these complicated parameters into the app? Can we use argparse? Is that even possible? Maybe we should use an INI file instead".     We are not yet ready to discuss HOW to use argparse, because we don't even know yet if we CAN. As a generic help, can you state which S.E site is best suited for "can this be done"? type questions? Thanks.

Comment: as currently written, the question reads more like how to use it for a concrete coding task: _"Can I use argparse to parse something like `myprpgrm.py --user john --email john@doe.com --valid Y --user jane --email jane@doe.com --valid N?"_

Comment: Can you help me rephrase it then? When I wrote "Can I use", I meant "is it possible?". Tell you what, I'll make that change. Please let me know if it is acceptable. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest phrasing your question less in terms of what is *possible* and more in terms of what is *reasonable*.  Lots of things are possible.  That doesn't mean they're maintainable, or good ideas in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use command line arguments for this.  Command line arguments are meant for simple, transient configuration.  What you have here is structured data.  You want to put it into a more permanent format, such as JSON:

```
[
    {
        'user': 'john',
        'email': 'john@doe.com',
        'valid': true
    },
    {
        'user': 'jane',
        'email': 'jane@doe.com',
        'valid': false
    }
]
```

Python conveniently has a module for parsing JSON:

```
import json

with open('path/to/data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

Argparse has [special facilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects) for passing files on the command line; you probably won't have to call `open()` by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin (+1). I am leaning towards .INI files and importing configparser, but JSON is also a good possibility. I will think which can best suit the sort of data which I am expecting. I do agree that it is probably too complex for a human to pass to the command line - I was originally thinking to add a GUI to invoke the command line based program, but am now leaning heavily towards having the data in a file.

Comment: Three years later, I though that I would let you know that I did, after all, go with  JSON. Thanks :-)